# Powershell Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to create a custom hash table using the following code but I'm not getting any output

```
foreach ($user in $users){
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "\\192.168.1.2\c$\user\$user"
$totalsize = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).sum / 1mb
$totalsize = [decimal]::round($totalsize) 

$output=@{"User"="$user" ; "Size" = "$totalsize"}
```

Comment: And if you add this as the last line of your foreach statement: `$output`?  Currently you have nothing in this statement that actually outputs anything.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work better?

```
$Output = 
 foreach ($user in $users){
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "\\192.168.1.2\c$\user\$user"
  $totalsize = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).sum / 1mb
  $totalsize = [decimal]::round($totalsize)
  @{"User"="$user" ; "Size" = "$totalsize"}
  }

$output
```

Comment: Yup, I actually had it as a function already but didn't realize I could start the hash without anything in front of it.  Thanks!